# Prestashop customers groups

Tags: php, prestashop

Prestashop 1.7.5.2

I have a group of customers in particular (the 43). For this group of customers, I would like that from the "my account" section, there is a link that directs to a list of specific products to add to the basket and only these products (which I will select by id I imagine ).
This option should only be available for customer group 43.
I really have no idea how to do it.
Do you have any ideas I could explore?

Thanks a lot

A list of specific product for a specific customers group to add to the basket

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to restrict your customer group to access a single category to which you will need to link the products you intend to offer.

Then you'll need to develop a simple module hooked into the customer display account hook to display a link to that category, if customer belongs to that ID group.

If you are not familiar with Prestashop and module development there are a few concepts you will have to learn, you can start [here](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, I cannot restrict my customer group to access a single category because this customer group must retain the possibility of buying all the products. But they need a new page with the products concerned to facilitate their access.
Thanks for the documentation. I code a little on Prestashop, but it's really the ideas that I miss here

Comment: Well, even with these requirements, the idea remains the same, just link your products with a customer group dedicated category so you'll have a category URL pointing to that category.

Comment: Thanks @user3256843 for your help
I did not specify that i can't create special categories for these products.That's how I have to deal with
If I understand, I can make:
-A module using the displayCustomerAccount hook
-An if condition to check the client group 43
-Show a link to the new page (With a new .tpl file I guess?)
-Select the list of desired products to display (I could perhaps use the getProducts() function of classes/Category.php and add a where clause at the end with the IDs of the products concerned, should I override this class?)
Still a student, I'm confused on this task

Comment: You say "you  can't create special categories for these products" but I guess you will have to group these special products somehow... the easiest way to do this is with a category (perhaps hidden or secondary). so you will be facilitated in creating the link to be shown to customers, you only need to call the native method of the Link class (getCategoryLink) to get the link to pass to your custom TPL. i hope this facilitate your work

Comment: I must clarify that my line manager does not want me to create special categories for these products. That's how I have to deal with...
But yes, it helps me i guess